# R count number of distincts not consistent

Tags: r

```
library(dplyr)
```

`distinct(mtcars, mpg)` displays the unique occurrences of mpg classes in mtcars.

`n_distinct(mtcars, mpg)` counts them and displays the correct count `32`.

`distinct(mtcars, cyl)` displays the unique occurrences of cylinder classes in mtcars.

`n_distinct(mtcars, cyl)` yields an error. Why doesn't it work like the mpg example above? I get this incorrect error... the object cyl is in the mtcars data frame, I assure you of that.

> ```
> Error in n_distinct_multi(list(...), na.rm) : object 'cyl' not found
> ```

Comment: You must have done something with mpg. If you start a fresh session and run `n_distinct(mtcars, mpg)`  you will also get an error.  Try `ls()`  and see if you have created an object called `mpg`.

Comment: There is an `mpg` object in ggplot2 which you likely have loaded.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `dplyr::n_distinct()` function is not a table verb like `mutate()`, `filter()`, etc. Its `...` parameter should be "vectors of values" (per official documentation).

So when you say `dplyr::n_distinct(mtcars, mpg)`, what is really happening 
is that the unique values of the first argument `mtcars` are being counted.

Since it has 32 distinct rows, the value is `32`. In the final example you 
provide, `cyl` is not recognized because there is no object called `cyl` -- the reason that `mpg` *is* being recognized is that `mpg` refers to the 
dataset `ggplot2::mpg`, *not* to the column of `mtcars` with the same name!

To see what I mean, run the following:

```
dplyr::n_distinct(mtcars)                # 32 
dplyr::n_distinct(ggplot2::mpg)          # 225 
dplyr::n_distinct(mtcars, mpg)           # 32 
dplyr::n_distinct(mtcars, ggplot2::mpg)  # 32
```

If you want to count the number of unique values in `mtcars$cyl` and `mtcars$mpg`, 
then just use:

```
dplyr::n_distinct(mtcars$cyl) # 3 
dplyr::n_distinct(mtcars$mpg) # 25
```

A tricky one!

Answer (score 3):

Your call to `n_distinct(mtcars, mpg)` is not returning the correct value, which would be 25. Instead, this line is giving you the number of unique rows in the whole table `mtcars`, which is 32 according to the output of `distinct(mtcars)`.

What you want to call is `n_distinct(mtcars$mpg)` which returns 25, or similarly on the `cyl` column you would want to say `n_distinct(mtcars$cyl)` or `n_distinct(mtcars[["cyl"]])` (equivalent).

```
> distinct(mtcars, cyl)
  cyl
1   6
2   4
3   8
> n_distinct(mtcars$cyl)
[1] 3
```